# web-scraping with rvest: filtering through paginanation

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am fairly new to R and have been trying to work with the "Rvest" package.

I am currently trying to scrape data from the website [Zillow](http://www.zillow.com).

My goal is to be able to find house prices, number of bedrooms, number of baths, and square footage by house.

Googling this, I was able to find some code from Hadley on GitHub. This was quite helpful however after running this I noticed that it could only bring back one page at a time.

I am wanting to be able to see a total list of houses with the above attributes associated with each house.

I know that when I try to filter through the websites "Pagination" it only lets me look at one page at a time. This specific websearch has 20 pages in total.

I can see that within the URL the only thing that changes is this at the end:

Original URL (page 1) = `https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Charlotte-NC/24043_rid/globalrelevanceex_sort/35.479124,-80.39177,34.929289,-81.270676_rect/9_zm/`

URL (page 2) = `https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Charlotte-NC/24043_rid/globalrelevanceex_sort/35.479124,-80.39177,34.929289,-81.270676_rect/9_zm/2_p/`

With `/2_p/` being the only thing changing.

If you were to go to page 3 then it would say `/3_p/` and etc...

Is there a way to loop through all pages, and save the attributes into a data frame and then access that data frame afterwards?

Here is the code I am using:

```
# Inspired by https://github.com/notesofdabbler
library(rvest)
library(tidyr)

page <- read_html("https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Charlotte-NC/24043_rid/globalrelevanceex_sort/35.304479,-80.247574,35.104743,-81.414871_rect/9_zm/")

houses <- page %>%
  html_nodes(".photo-cards li article")

z_id <- houses %>% html_attr("id")

address <- houses %>%
  html_node(".zsg-photo-card-address") %>%
  html_text()

price <- houses %>%
  html_node(".zsg-photo-card-price") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  readr::parse_number()

params <- houses %>%
  html_node(".zsg-photo-card-info") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  strsplit("&middot;")

beds = params %>% purrr::map_chr(1) %>% readr::parse_number()
baths <- params %>% purrr::map_chr(1) %>% readr::parse_number()
house_area <- params %>% purrr::map_chr(1) %>% readr::parse_number()


df_price = data.frame(price)

df_beds = data.frame(beds)

df_baths = data.frame(baths)

df_house_area = data.frame(house_area)
```

Thank you!

Comment: FYI - there is a [`ZillowR` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ZillowR/index.html)

Comment: @JasonAizkalns I know but I want to increase my Rvest knowledge by using this package. After this I want to scrape other forms of webpages and I’m not sure if Rzillow can allow me to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create the 'links' with `sprintf`

```
library(tidyverse)
links <- sprintf("https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Charlotte-NC/24043_rid/globalrelevanceex_sort/35.479124,-80.39177,34.929289,-81.270676_rect/9_zm/%d_p", 1:20)
```

and then loop through the links to scrape the data into a single `data.frame`

```
res <- map(links, ~ {

         houses <- read_html(.x) %>%
                html_nodes(".photo-cards li article")
         z_id <- houses %>% 
                    html_attr("id")

         address <- houses %>%
                html_node(".zsg-photo-card-address") %>%
                html_text()

         price <- houses %>%
             html_node(".zsg-photo-card-price") %>%
             html_text() %>%
             readr::parse_number()

        params <- houses %>%
             html_node(".zsg-photo-card-info") %>%
             html_text() %>%
             strsplit("&middot;")

        beds <- params %>%
             str_extract("\\d+(?=\\s*bds)") %>%
             as.numeric()
        baths <- params %>% 
             str_extract("\\d+(?=\\s*ba)") %>%
             as.numeric()
        house_area <- params %>%
               str_extract("[0-9,]+(?=\\+*\\s*sqft)") %>%
               str_replace(",", "") %>%
               as.numeric

data_frame(price = price, beds= beds, baths=baths, house_area = house_area)

                 }
                 ) %>%

    bind_rows(.id = 'page_no')
```

-output

```
res
# A tibble: 500 x 5
#   page_no   price  beds baths house_area
#   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 1       1995000  5.00  7.00       8110
# 2 1        325000  3.00  2.00       1897
# 3 1       1099000  5.00  4.00       3532
# 4 1        550990  4.00  4.00       2953
# 5 1        323000  5.00  3.00       3100
# 6 1        315000  3.00  3.00       1723
# 7 1       2600000  5.00  7.00       7124
# 8 1       1300000  5.00  5.00       4737
# 9 1        549900  2.00  2.00       1788
#10 1        538000  5.00  4.00       3595
# ... with 490 more rows
```

-checking the extracted info with the first few postings on page 1

[image]